# opencv: performing night vision

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

First I am not talking about real night vision. I am talking about the technique used to improve picture brightness/light when light condition is poor. You can see this technique perfectly in smart phones, superb in phablets. I know the technique used in here, get the existing light and used it to make the pic clear. But how to do this in opencv? Any method or step by step process?

Comment: Look into gamma correction, but in general you need to be interacting with the camera to get Auto Gain Control (AGC) (I also suggest auto exposure control if you can get away with it).

Comment: That is dependent on hardware. Even in smart phones, "fake" night vision is accomplished by toggling NIR blocking filter. You can verify this by taking a picture of remote control pressed. So as far as I know there is no way to emulate night vision except for adjusting gamma or brightness of images with OpenCV.

Comment: Before gamma correction you need to clean up your image: remove bias and make slight median filtering. Otherwise your image will be very noisy.

Answer (score 2):

There are essentially 2 ways to brighten your image:

1. Get more photons in the camera
2. Give each photon more 'weight'

For approach 1, supposing that you can't control the lighting, then the only way to get more photons is to expose your sensor for a longer period of time.  That assumes that you can change your camera's integration time.  The drawback of this approach is that you can get more motion blur.

For approach 2, this amounts to applying a multiplicative gain to the input image, which makes each photon contribute more DN's to the resulting image.  Applying such a gain though supposes that you have a priori information about the input image's brightness.  If your gain value is not good you'll have an image that's either saturated or too dark.

To improve your image automatically, the best approach would be to use OpenCV's equalizeHist function, as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html).  The operation isn't exactly a multiplicative gain but the effect is similar.

The last step would be, as previously suggested in comments, to apply a gamma correction as described [here](http://vaamarnath.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/opencv-gamma-correction/).  Gamma correction tends to reduce the contrast in an image, but since you improved the contrast using histogram equalization you should get good results.

Comment: wow wow wow! This method seems to be very cool and advanced! Is there anyway I can contact you personally for these issues until my project is done???

Answer (score 1):

As Michel points out try equalizeHist.
Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    namedWindow("input");
    namedWindow("output");
    Mat in = imread("yourDarkImage.jpg");;
    Mat out;

    if(in.empty())exit(1);

    //equalize histograms per channel
    vector<Mat> colors;
    split(in, colors);
    equalizeHist(colors[0], colors[0]);
    equalizeHist(colors[1], colors[1]);
    equalizeHist(colors[2], colors[2]);
    merge(colors, out);

    imshow("input", in);
    imshow("output", out);


    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would do better in HSV colour space and equalise only the Y (lum) channel. Alternately just do it for a black+white image. Equalising each colour channel will produce odd (pyschodelic) colour effects

Comment: wow wow wow! I need to try this out! Is there anyway I can contact you personally for these issues until my project is done???